# Convert Textbox string to Double VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, tryparse

i'm getting a problem everytime I try to convert an textbox value to a double, the value in the textbox will be used in a calculation with another double, and it's entried from keyboard, everytime i tried to run it I used just numbers on the textbox.

```
    dim temporaryProduct as string
    Dim value, convertValue, finalValue As Double

temporaryProduct = mathForm.valueBox.tostring ' I've tried with .text too

            If Double.TryParse(temporaryProduct, value) Then 'Convert to double
                convertValue = value
            Else
                MsgBox("Tryparse error")
                Exit Sub
            End If
```

Everytime i try to convert the textbox string i get "Tryparse error", i really don't know what i'm doing wrong, and i need it to be in double.

Comment: Use the debugger to see what value you're actually trying to parse, and you'll see that it isn't a number.

Comment: Are your locales correct? Try to replace . with , and see if that works.

Comment: Looks like you are not getting the right value out of mathForm.valueBox .  What is valueBox?

Comment: What decimal separator was used? If you expect `.` use `Double.TryParse(temporaryProduct, NumberStyles.Any, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, value)`.

Comment: valueBox is a textbox, I really don't know what is wrong here ... it worked a lot of other times...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using just the Text property:

```
temporaryProduct = mathForm.valueBox.Text
```

If you use the ToString function on a TextBox, you get something like this:

> System.Windows.Forms.TextBox, Text: ???

which is obviously not a value you can use.

Comment: I tried to use the .text too, and i still can't convert it to double, just get the same problem.
Maybe i'm missing something in another place...

Comment: @Altrunox What is the value of mathForm.valueBox.Text when you run this?

Comment: I've made another noobish mistake, i tried to get the value of mathForm.valueBox.Text and i get a blank string, i missed that everytime i tried to calculate the value the textbox was cleared, i fixed it, Thx.